# Identify consecutive not nan values at the end

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan, missing-data

How to get the last part of consecutive not `NaN` values in a table? For example:

```
   col
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  NaN
3  NaN
4  3.0
5  NaN
6  4.0
7  5.0
8  6.0
```

Desired result:

```
   col
6  4.0
7  5.0
8  6.0
```

My solution:

```
df[df.col[::-1].isna().cumsum()[::-1].eq(0)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way you can do this -

```
df[df.loc[::-1, 'col'].isna().cumsum()[::-1]==0]
```

```
    col
6   4.0
7   5.0
8   6.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
last_index = df[df.col.isna()].index[-1]
df.iloc[last_index + 1:]
```

output:

```
    col
6   4.0
7   5.0
8   6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
last_index = np.where(df.col.isna())[0][-1]
df.iloc[last_index+1:]
```